# Проблема с axios или vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios

Проблема с получение данных в vue. Моя идея в том, чтобы в главном компоненте App, на хуке created делать запрос по axios и в ранее пустую модель закинуть данные из ответа, но проблема в том, что при переназначении модели currencies она внезапно становится undefined. Пробовал выводить вместо currencies именно ответ сервера, все работает, только лишь с моделькой ругается. Моделька мне нужна для provide/inject. Извиняюсь если задал, что-то легкое, во вьюшке только разбираюсь потихоньку

````
import AppBtnList from "./components/AppBtnList.vue";
import AppDisplay from "./components/AppDisplay.vue";
export default {
  components: { AppDisplay, AppBtnList },
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      currencies: [],
    };
  },

  created() {
    const axios = require("axios");
    axios
      .get("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/latest.js")
      .then(function (response) {
        this.currencies = response.data.rates;
        console.log(this.currencies);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // обработка ошибки
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
};
</script>```
````

Comment: Так this внутри анонимной функции это уже другой контекст. Поменяйте на стрелочную функцию колбэк и все заработает

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Используя вместо axios обычный fetch можно избежать ошибки